# CSS line-height vertical center IE9+

Tags: html, css

I have several elements throughout the page that use line-height to center the single line text vertically in their fixed height container. This has been working fine in other browsers, but in IE the text appears higher than normal.

Using IE's emulation I found it works as expected in IE8, but everything above that the text is offset. Am I missing something?

Eg.

```
#button {
  display:inline-block;
  height:50px;
  line-height:50px;
}    
<a href="#" id="button">My Text</a>
```

Comment: It looks fine to me? http://jsfiddle.net/nzv3fgwu/

Comment: Adding this tag in the head sometimes helps IE behave like other browsers: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

Comment: Updated the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nzv3fgwu/1/ seems to be something to do with the font

Comment: @user500665 when viewing your JS.Fiddle you forgot to add at
import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen); but even when I do it still looks fine to me in IE9 and IE10. You can see the [updated JS.Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/nzv3fgwu/2/)

Comment: Haven't used jsfiddle before so maybe I'm doing it wrong there but I added this under external resources: <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

Comment: @crazymatt Can't upload images here yet but here is what I get from your fiddle:  http://tinypic.com/r/255hsad/8  -IE is Top, Firefox is Bottom

Comment: @crazymatt Also should note, my IE is version 11 on windows 7.

Comment: @user500665 I am unable to reproduce what you are seeing. Do you have the latest updates to IE11? My version number is 11.0.9600.17914

Comment: @crazymatt So it's just my IE that's annoying... My version is 11.0.9600.18015